# One form to generate two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I'm facing a problem that I couldn't find a solution yet.

I want to have a single page form that will generate two different models. Is that possible?
For example, when the user presses the submit button, some of the input will be used to generate the User model and other inputs will be used to generate a Pharmacy model.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think model is not what you meant to say? Do you want model (Eg. user model) or database entry(Eg. one new user)?

Comment: It's true, I said it wrong. The model already exists and I want to create a new entry for that (two) model(s) at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will use a `form_for` and pass in the parent object. Then, when you get to the fields for the other object, you can use the `fields_for` method and pass in the other object. Then in the model you can do something like:

```
def pharmacy_attributes=(attributes)
  @pharmacy = Pharmacy.create(attributes)
  self.pharmacy = @pharmacy
  save
end
```

If you are using rails 4 you will have to allow the nested attributes in the controller and add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :pharmacy` to the user model if that is the way your relationships are set up.

Comment: Thanks CWitty. I found some tutorials following your solution and I got stuck here, see if you can help me. I created in Pharmacy this: accepts_nested_attributes_for :users.. and then I added to the pharmacy_controller this line in the new action: @pharmacy.users.build.. and I added to my pharmacy form the fields_for :users.. but it doesn't show the fiels for the user. It seems the :users is empty or something like this.. Thanks!

Comment: In your controller do @user= User.new. Then in the form you can do fields_for @user do |u| and build the user fields like u.text_field :first_name. Etc

Comment: Found out what the problem was. I was doing <% f.fields_for :users do |s| %> instead of <%= f.fields_for @user do |s| %>... The '=' symbol in '<%=' for rails 4! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following code climate blog post:

http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Of particular interest will be section: "3. Extract Form Objects"